# Why are the effects of vertical align: text bottom and vertical align: bottom consistent？

Tags: html, css

The position of the line box’s baseline is affected by all elements in that line.

```css
      .short-box {
        width: 30px;
        height: 30px;
        background-color: pink;
        display: inline-block;
      }
      .box {
        background-color: bisque;
        margin-bottom: 10px;
      }
      .tall-box {
        width: 30px;
        height: 100px;
        background-color: pink;
        display: inline-block;
      }
      .text-bottom {
        vertical-align: text-bottom;
      }
      .text-top {
        vertical-align: text-top;
      }

      .bottom {
        vertical-align: bottom;
      }
      .top {
        vertical-align: top;
      }
```

```html
  <body>
    <div class="box">
      x
      <span class="tall-box text-bottom"></span>
      <span class="short-box"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="box">
      x
      <span class="tall-box text-top"></span>
      <span class="short-box"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="box">
      x
      <span class="tall-box bottom"></span>
      <span class="short-box"></span>
    </div>

    <div class="box">
      x
      <span class="tall-box top"></span>
      <span class="short-box"></span>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

[image]

Why are the effects of the first box and the third box the same, but the effects of the second box and the fourth box are different. How does the vertical align attribute change the baseline of the line box?

Comment: you are with span, even inline-block, still inline. Second, you put class text-top with vertical-align text-top. All inline in the actual block will take same

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In brief, because the short box sticks out above the parent content box, but does not stick out below the parent content box.

---

Here's your image with the relevant boxes and lines added:

[image: The four variations of the aligned boxes each with the line box, root inline content box and baseline depicted]

In each case, the green rectangle shows where the line box is, the blue rectangle shows where the parent content box is, and the red line shows where the baseline is.

Now we can see that in both the cases one and three, where the tall box aligns with `text-bottom` and `bottom` respectively, the bottom of the parent content box and the bottom of the line box are coincident. Hence the alignment of each resolves to the same arrangement.

In cases two and four, where the tall box aligns with `text-top` and `top` respectively, the top of the parent content box and the top of the line box are not coincident, so they do not layout the same.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. In the `Movement Of the Line Box's Baseline` chapter of this linked post, its text top performance is inconsistent with mine.https://christopheraue.net/design/vertical-align#centering-an-icon

Comment: @Dasheng - The critical detail here is the height of the short box relative to the font size of the parent, i.e. the height of the parent's content box, or what the article calls the "text box". If the font's ascent is greater than the short box's height, then the behaviour matches what the article describes. The article isn't clear about that relationship.